# Insert row into a table with foreign key

Tags: sql

I have created two tables (`SupplierName` and `SupplierAddress`) in the `address_book` database.

Table `SupplierName` has one row inserted as shown in the insert statement below. I am struggling how to insert data into the table called `SupplierAddress`.

Please note that the `SupplierID` (primary key) from the `SupplierName` table is the foreign key in the `SupplierAddress` table. If my table design is incorrect please opine on that as well. I am just trying to create a simple database to learn SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE SupplierName
(
    SupplierID int Primary Key identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CompanyName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    EIN char(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE SupplierAddress
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(50),
    City varchar(50),
    State char(2),
    ZipCode char(5),
    Phone varchar(10),
    SupplierAddressID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SupplierName(SupplierID)
)

INSERT INTO SupplierName (CompanyName, EIN)
VALUES ('Clarks Electronics, Inc.', '123456789');

INSERT INTO SupplierAddress (Address, City, State, ZipCode, Phone)
VALUES ('2020 Garnet Road', 'York', 'PA', '17403', '717-123-4567')

SELECT
    SupplierName.SupplierID, SupplierAddress.SupplierAddressID 
FROM
    SupplierName
INNER JOIN 
    SupplierAddress ON SupplierAddressID=SupplierID
```

Comment: What error message is it giving you, on what command?  The INSERT SupplierAddress or the Select that follows?  Is there a missing ";" semi-colon between the two?

Comment: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 26
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the hyphens from the phone number, or create table with more characters in phone

Look at http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm to pretty format the sql

```
CREATE TABLE supplieraddress
  (
     id                INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
     address           VARCHAR(50),
     city              VARCHAR(50),
     state             CHAR(2),
     zipcode           CHAR(5),
     phone             VARCHAR(10),  -- make this longer
     supplieraddressid INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES suppliername(supplierid)
  ) 


INSERT INTO supplieraddress
            (address,
             city,
             state,
             zipcode,
             phone)
-- add  supplieraddressid  and its value so that the FK is created
VALUES     ('2020 Garnet Road',
            'York',
            'PA',
            '17403',
            '717-123-4567')  -- or  remove hyphens

SELECT suppliername.supplierid,
       supplieraddress.supplieraddressid
FROM   suppliername
       INNER JOIN supplieraddress
               ON supplieraddressid = supplierid
```

Comment: I removed the hyphens and it works now. However, SupplierAddressID is null when I insert the above row.

Comment: Yes, in the pasted code see where I suggested add the FK